# How to get rid of blank pages?

Tags: tables, graphics, emptypage

I am having issues with unnecessary blank pages (in the Appendix in particular).

I've tried to reproduce a minimal example.

```
%------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[headings=standardclasses]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=20mm, bottom=25mm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}

% to fit large table (change geometry of single page)
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{flushleft}
\huge \textbf{Report} \\
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\normalsize
June 2021 \\
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\textsc{Author}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\end{flushleft}


\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-3]
% ...
% ...
% ...


\begin{landscape}
\begin{appendices}
\section{Results}


\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    523 & 532 \\
    532 & 123
\end{tabular}

\newpage \begin{tabular}{c|c}
    523 & 532 \\
    532 & 123
\end{tabular}


\newpage
\section{Histograms}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure} \\
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure} \\
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Histograms}
\end{figure}

\end{appendices}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Here are two images (from my original file) of what I am having issues with.

The first empty blank page (wasn't able to reproduce this in my minimal example):

[image]

The second empty blank page (can be seen in the minimal example too):
[image]

I suspect the blank pages appear due to things not being able to fit in the same page. I am willing to scale down the sizes if that would fix the issues. I tried multiple things but am just not able to fix it.

Any help would be much appreciated; thanks for reading!

Comment: you posted a lot of code but no one can run it to see the problem as it uses files we don't have. Try to make a small self contained example (you can use `example-image` as the image which is available for tests. Note that `\noindent\begin{figure}[ht]` will make bad output `\noindent` applies at that point but the purpose of `figure` is to take the content out of the text flow and insert elsewhere. figures are never indented in any case.  `[ht]` prevents a figure being placed on a float page, so makes it more likely to go to the end of the document (or next `\clearpage`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your response, I will replace the images with example-image

Comment: Just a guess, but it could be due to LaTeX trying NOT to put a figure (or float?) directly at the beginning of a chapter, in this case the appendix. I had this problem using the same document class. Btw, I believe the author of the class suggests to use his typearea package instead of geometry in his class.

Comment: @Philipp Thanks for your input. I just tried changing the document class to "article", but that didn't fix the issue

Comment: I tried to run your example and it stops with `! LaTeX Error: Environment spacing undefined.` Please test that the posted code makes the output shown

Comment: Or try using [h] also for your subfigures (didn’t try it myself).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ugh, so sorry for wasting your time. I didn't realise there was an error as it worked on overleaf. I've fixed it now, should work. Thanks so much

Comment: No it would have errored on overleaf as well, If overleaf shows a small red circle ignore the pdf output!

Comment: latex does warn `Overfull \hbox (195.90038pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 62--77` so this isn't going to fit....

Comment: Your code works the way you intend if you just remove one of the subfigures. three on top of each other are just too high when the section heading is also displayed.

Comment: the figure fits under the histograms heading if you use `[htp!]`

Comment: Or replace the 0.5 with 0.4 scale for all five subfigures

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried [htp!] but the figures become vertical for some reason. Thanks for your help. I think reducing the plot sizes is the way to go.

Comment: @Philipp thanks to you too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing `[ht]` to `[ht!]` seems to solve the problem:

```
%------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[headings=standardclasses]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm, top=20mm, bottom=25mm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}

% to fit large table (change geometry of single page)
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{flushleft}
\huge \textbf{Report} \\
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\normalsize
June 2021 \\
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\textsc{Author}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\end{flushleft}


\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-3]
% ...
% ...
% ...


\begin{landscape}
\begin{appendices}
\section{Results}


\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    523 & 532 \\
    532 & 123
\end{tabular}

\newpage \begin{tabular}{c|c}
    523 & 532 \\
    532 & 123
\end{tabular}


\newpage
\section{Histograms}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure} \\
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure} \\
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Histograms}
\end{figure}

\end{appendices}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

[image]